# Exception handling in GRPC - return common object

Tags: c#, exception, microservices, grpc, proto

I googled a lot C# articles how to proceed with that with interceptors. I can divide them on 2 types:

1. Rethrow RPCException
2. return default

My problem, i want to return back some common API response object.

```
public class GrpcResponseBase
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

public class GrpcResponse<TData> : GrpcResponseBase
    {
        public TData Data { get; set; }

        ...
    }
```

So all the objects i return to client need to be based on that. And the object returned from exception handler too.

But that's the problem. The response objects are autogenerated by protobuf compiler from proto files. Proto doesn't support inheritance, and i don't want to copy-paste those 2-3 fields each time for each "message". And i think it doesn't support generics too.

What can i do ? Maybe don't use interceptors, but use something else ? Please suggest